# Vehicle live update in Azure map using IoT Hub

Tags: angular7, azure-iot-hub, azure-maps

I am created a vehicle management web application in .NET core. And here we can manage vehicle. And when a user login, he can view full details of his vehicle. And also provide current location of the vehicle in the map. And when the vehicle moves  he want to see the moving live update in Map. Is it possible to show the live moving in map. I am checked Azure Map. But I have not get full idea to how to implement Azure map and IoT hub in my application. If anyone used this type of live update in Azure map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you receive the geo-location data from the device?

If yes, you could have for example as the simplest solution, an Azure function with SignalR service. With Azure function, you consume and get the geolocation data from the IoT Hub. 
Also, in Azure function, you make the mapping between the device and client/user which should receive this information(if you need that), and then use the SignalR to send that message to that specific user.

In the web app, you also use SIgnalR to receive these specific messages with geo location, and with Azure maps javascript sdk try to show the latest location. For example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-pin) by adding a pin(and removing the previous one), or something similar.

I haven't tried this, but this is something I would do as a POC to see how it would work. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Here is a sample showing real-time data on Azure Maps: https://github.com/davetheunissen/Global-Azure-Bootcamp-2019-Workshop

Comment: Thank you, I have one doubt, the device sending location when the vehicle moving. And also when the device send data i want to save some information from the device. Is it possible? I checked azure Time series. Is that work ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-iot-hub-maps

Comment: @rbrundritt exactly! 
Jinesh you can have a look at the example from rbrundritt when it comes to signalR and Azure Maps. 
To answer your second question, yes, TSI can be convenient if you want to show how your processes/assets change over time. However, if you want to enrich your data in an event-driven manner, and use the data for later purposes, MSFT recommend IoT Reference architecture, that introduces concepts of cold, hot, and even warm data path, depending on how frequently and how time-critical the data you want to store is.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/iot/

Comment: So there are couple of ways to store your data. You can use stream analytics to store and partition your data in the different storages while coming through the IoT Hub, and also writes the data to the event-hub so that you can have your Azure Function with SignalR to send data back to the map. 
Or you can have consumer groups on IoT Hub. One consumer group for Stream analytics, the other one for Azure function. Long story short, there are different ways to accomplish the same, depending on your concrete requirements.

Comment: Also, later you can think about how Azure functions scale, but tha discussion is not black or white :)

Comment: You might also find these useful: https://github.com/kartben/azure-iot-realtime-asset-tracking-workshop and https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/84343?source=sessions

Comment: @rbrundritt ,@kgalic how can I catch the geofence in vehicle movements.

Comment: @Jinesh, can you please be more specific, or open another question for the dedicated topic?

Comment: I want to send push notifications to Admin, when a vehicle In or Out the geofence region. The geofence region details saved in mt SQL database. So how can I catch the geofence.?

Comment: In your azure function, you can fetch the geofence from the db and compare it with the incoming message coordinates. If it is out, then you can forward the message to the service bus queue(additional one), and use the Logic app to send an email or so..

Comment: @kgalic that's good idea. But I have one doubt , if we fetch the geofence from the db using API call(approximately 3k vehicle in a minute) , does it work properly? Large ammount of API call will hit

Comment: How about caching the geofence somewhere, as it does not change very frequently, I assume? Redis cache, or a maybe cheaper version like blob store in a plain JSON? - Assuming that in most of the cases will be read-only